# Скопировать каталог с подкаталогами

Tags: c++, winapi

Здравствуйте я пытаюсь написать рекурсивную функцию используя `WIN32_FIND_DATA` для того что бы скопировать каталог в нужное место все его файлы, все его подкаталоги, и файлы в них но немного запутался в логике. Не могли бы вы привести пример как я могу это сделать?

Comment: ShFileoperation или системная команда copy/xcopy -  не вариант, как я понимаю?  А просто вывести список файлов с подкаталогами получается?

Comment: Используйте `<filesystem>`

Comment: Зачем вам WinAPI? Есть стандартная крассплатформенная библиотека STL Filesystem!

Comment: `system("xcopy.....` :-)

Comment: Не факт, что использование `<filesystem>` хорошая идея, если нет планов на кросс-платформу. Возможно, `<filesystem>` является дефолтным выбором, но иногда полезно получить доступ к фичам платформы или избежать баги стандартной библиотеки